# What does PN mean on this capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, components, markings

What does PN mean on this capacitor?

[image]

Comment: Naming like that is completely down to a manufacturer - no idea who uses that symbol.  Suffixes on capacitors usually indicate thinks like lead form and tolerance.

Comment: Right ^^  Might be 'lot code' even.  Could be anything, but it's not something you'll likely figure out.